# Undefined function 'symsum' for input arguments of type 'double'. for terahert band system model

Tags: matlab

I am trying to code a system model in the terahert band
This is my code and I have this error
Undefined function 'symsum' for input arguments of type 'double'.

```
close all; clear all;
clc


freq = 275*10^9;
eta = 4;
c= 3*10^8;
gt=10^5.5;
gr=gt;
d=30;
lambda = c/freq;
k=THz_Pathloss(freq);
path_gain_thz= ((c*sqrt(gt*gr))./(4*pi*freq*d)).*exp(-0.5*k*d); % hL = hAL * hFL
signal_bw = 10*10^9;
noise_psd = 3.8*10^(-17);
noise_power = noise_psd*signal_bw;
signal_power_dbm= -20:10:60;
signal_power_lin = 10.^(signal_power_dbm/10)*10^(-3);
power_noise_ratio_db = 20:10:60;    %signal_power_dbm-noise_power_dbm;
power_noise_ratio = 10.^(power_noise_ratio_db/10);

cc=symsum(signal_bw,6)*log2*{1+ (2/noise_psd*k)};
```

Undefined function 'symsum' for input arguments of type 'double'.

Error in Energy_Model_WSNN (line 19)
cc=symsum(signal_bw,6)*log2*{1+ (2/noise_psd*k)};

Comment: well, you are not using symbolic math and trying to use the symbolic math toolbox `symsum`. What do you want to do there? just `sum`?

Comment: If it is your code, what do you expect that line to do? As it stands it looks like you're trying to call a function call `symsum` and that function doesn't exist, just like the error message says. The `symsum` function is part of the symbolic toolbox, so you probably don't have that installed (probably because you don't have a licence for the toolbox). But do you really intend to do symbolic math?
But as I said, you need to explain what you intend for this line to do? See [ask].

Comment: If it is your code, what do you expect that line to do? As it stands it looks like you're trying to call a function call `symsum` and that function doesn't exist, just like the error message says. The `symsum` function is part of the symbolic toolbox, so you probably don't have that installed (probably because you don't have a licence for the toolbox). But do you really intend to do symbolic math?
But as I said, you need to explain what you intend for this line to do? See [ask].

Comment: I was trying to write the terahertz channel capacity according to Shannon formula.